# How do I structure a database cache (memcached/Redis) for a Python web app with many different variables for querying?

Tags: python, database, caching, redis, memcached

For my app, I am using Flask, however the question I am asking is more general and can be applied to any Python web framework.

I am building a comparison website where I can update details about products in the database. I want to structure my app so that 99% of users who visit my website will never need to query the database, where information is instead retrieved from the cache (memcached or Redis).

I require my app to be realtime, so any update I make to the database must be instantly available to any visitor to the site. Therefore I do not want to cache views/routes/html.

I want to cache the entire database. However, because there are so many different variables when it comes to querying, I am not sure how to structure this. For example, if I were to cache every query and then later need to update a product in the database, I would basically need to flush the entire cache, which isn't ideal for a large web app.

I would prefer is to cache individual rows within the database. The problem is, how do I structure this so I can flush the cache appropriately when an update is made to the database? Also, how can I map all of this together from the cache?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Caching database rows is not going to give a large advantage. What you have to cache are results of complex queries or computations. But frankly speaking you are asking for a caching concept, which is out of the scope of SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So a free eBook called "Redis in Action" by Josiah Carlson answered all of my questions. It it quite long, but after reading through, I have a fairly solid understanding of how to structure a caching architecture. It gives real world examples, such as a social network and a shopping site with tons of traffic. I will need to read through it again once or twice to fully understand. A great book!

Link: [Redis in Action](https://redislabs.com/ebook/redis-in-action)

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact question myself, with a PHP project, though. My solution was to use ElasticSearch as an intermediate cache between the application and database.

The trick to this is the ORM. I designed it so that when Entity.save() is called it is first stored in the database, then the complete object (with all references) is pushed to ElasticSearch and only then the transaction is committed and the flow is returned back to the caller.

This way I maintained full functionality of a relational database (atomic changes, transactions, constraints, triggers, etc.) and still have all entities cached with all their references (parent and child relations) together with the ability to invalidate individual cached objects.

Hope this helps.